# Find a counterexample for the following statement (explanation please, I already have the solution)

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

If $ac \equiv bc \pmod{m}$, where $a$, $b$, $c$, and $m$ are integers with $2 \le c < m$, then $a \equiv b \pmod{m}$.

Would I begin with:

$a \pmod{m} \equiv b \pmod{m}$ and $c \pmod{m} \equiv c \pmod{m}$?

I'm pretty much lost at where to go with this, I know it has to do with the fundamental congruency theorems but not sure how to use that to my advantage.

Comment: The missing assumption is that $\text{gcd}(c, m)$ is not assumed to be 1.  Thus, you might look at pairs of $c$ and $m$ whose gcd is not 1 to come up with a counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $m=8$, $a=6,b=4, c=4$.

*Idea* Note that $6\not\equiv 4\mod 8$, yet $8\mid 4\times 4$ and $8\mid6\times 4$, and indeed the problem is that $(4,8)=4\neq 1$.

If $(n,c)=1$ then we would have $xc+yn=1$ for some pair of integers $x,y$, whence $$cx\equiv 1\mod n$$

thus multiplying by $x$ and $c$ would let us go back and from between both equations.